# When trying to select a column of type BLOB, SQLStatement throws a RangeError #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air, blob

```
var imageData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var headshotStatement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
headshotStatement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
var headshotStr:String = "SELECT headshot FROM ac_images WHERE id = " + idx;
headshotStatement.text = headshotStr;
headshotStatement.execute();
```

Error references the final line in this block. I found a few references online where people are unable to select a BLOB using AS3 that has had data inserted into it from an external program, which is my exact situation.

Exact error trace is:

```
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
at flash.data::SQLStatement/internalExecute()
at flash.data::SQLStatement/execute()
at edu.bu::DataManager/getHeadshotImageData()[omitted/DataManager.as:396]
at edu.bu::CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow/editStudent()[omitted/CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow.mxml:194]
at edu.bu::CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow/profileEditor_completeHandler()[omitted/CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow.mxml:37]
at edu.bu::CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow/___CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow_Window1_creationComplete()[omitted/CustomStudentProfileEditorWindow.mxml:9]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12528]
at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1627]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:759]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1072]
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with the data that is causing AS3 to choke?

**Edit:** I've tried to insert the same data into a binary type field using SQLite Manager 3.5 for OS X with the same result. I'm working with a JPG, going to try other image formats, though I can't begin to guess which supplied index is out of bounds given that trying to jump to the definition just states that it's getting it from a SWC and I can't see. Grasping at straws before I distribute the data in a zip and decompress it on the fly, which I don't want to do.

**Edit 2, Workaround Edition:** For now, I've written a quick MXML Window that prompts for the images and inserts the data into the database. Would still love to know why another application can't store BLOB data in a way that SQLStatement understands. I'm essentially setting up a few buttons that prompt for file paths to the images I want in the database, reading them in with readBytes() to a ByteArray, and storing that into the SQLite db using SQLStatement. I am then able to read the image back without difficulty.

**Edit 3:** Here is an image of the table structure. Note, this same table is being used successfully when I have Flash do the database image insert, as opposed to some other tool which properly stores the data in the BLOB field for every other application but Flash...

[image: Table]

Comment: If you think this is a bug and don't have a solution, feel free to up vote the bug on Adobe's bug tracker: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-133

Comment: will it work for **SELECT * FROM ...**? could you show your sql table? i mean header with types please

Comment: As long as the blob type is involved in the select, the same error occurs, so no, * doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Air docs, CAST is supported to bring in non-AMF blobs as of Air 2.5.  I had the same issue with a database/blob field created in python and used in Air and this solved it for me.

example from docs:

```
stmt.text = "SELECT CAST(data AS ByteArray) AS data FROM pictures;"; 
stmt.execute(); 
var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult(); 
var bytes:ByteArray = result.data[0].data;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd47bd22bdd97276f1365b8c112629d7c47c-8000.html

Comment: I swear that never used to exist in the documentation :) Thanks!

Comment: np, I tried several complicated fixes based on answers here before coming across the simple way (wanted to make sure others didn't do the same)....I assume that feature wasn't in Air when the question was initially asked.

Comment: I did file a bug about it with Adobe...but it was never updated with any solution - heh

Answer (score 2):

I found your question because I have experienced the same problem.

I have finally been able to fix and solve my problem maybe you should look on my solution maybe this can help you solves yours: [What is the first bytes in a Blob column SQlite Adobe AIR? Blob Sizeinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388456/what-is-the-first-bytes-in-a-blob-column-sqlite-adobe-air-blob-sizeinfo)

It's all fault of Adobe AIR and AMF (ActionScript Message Format) which try to store the ByteArray object as a formatted binary. So it add a first byte 12 which is the TypeCode for the ByteArray followed by a int-29 integer for the size-length and finally the raw data.

So if you want to store a binary blob data into a sqlite which must be read by Adobe AIR you must add those informations to allow Adobe Air to convert everything back into a ByteArray.